# Prove that O(n^2) is better or worse than O(n^2 log n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

**My Question :** O(n^2) better or worse than O(n^2 log n)

I don't know if there exist any algorithm with O(n^2 log n), this question is from revision on Past Year Exam Question.
The question asked:

**Given four algorithms with the following time complexities, O(2n^2), O(n^2 log n), O(3n log n), and O(12n), ascending them in ascending growth rate.**

As my opinion, O(n^2 log n) is better when log n < 1, worse when log n >1.

As a conclusion to this, which is better between this 2

Thank you for anyone who viewed or answer this question.

Comment: In a complexity study, n always tends to infinite. It's always a very big number

Comment: You should always assume `n` is very big, so `log n > 1`. Then dismiss the factors `O(2n^2) = O(n^2)`. I won't answer your question directly, because you can: if `n` is 10000, is O(n^2) better or worse than O(n^2 * log n) ? Remember I just said `log n > 1` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put some value and prove it mathematically.. Take values of N where is the set of positive integers and solve the equation. Compare the results..

Answer (score 0):

When using the this notation for complexity of an algorithm you don't bother with small values of n, you only look at the big values, also any constants can be removed.

Here they are listed from highest complexity to the lowest:
O (n^2 log n)
O (2n^2) = O (n^2)
O (n log n)
O (12n) = O (n)